# Pinescript: How to plot horizontal line from daily candle close price if and only if price never returns to daily candle close price

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pinescript and would appreciate some insight on this.

I would like to have the script plot a horizontal line that extends right from a daily candle close if and only if the price never returns to that daily candle's close.

So far I have the following:

````
```

var line myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
var float prevDayofmonthClose = na

if dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1]
    // Move line
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index-1, close[1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index, close[1])

```
````

Unfortunately, this will plot the horizontal line from the previous daily candle close only and has no regard for whether or not price has returned to that price. Again, what I would like is for it to only plot the line if price has not returned to that closing price. And I would like this for all daily candles wherever price has not returned to that level.

Please see attached image that I have manually drawn, as an example of what the script output should look like.

[Here is a picture of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O00az.png)

Thank you!